# How to create array in PHP with strings from another array as position names?

Tags: php, arrays

Basically what I'm trying to do is create an array that has strings for their position names, such as:

```
$types = [
    "Methods" => array(),
    "Systems" => array(),
    "Equipment" => array()
]
```

This is what `var_dump($types)` results in:

```
array(3) { ["Methods"]=> array(0) { } ["Systems"]=> array(0) { } ["Equipment"]=> array(0) { } }
```

However, instead of declaring `$types` like this, I want to have an array `$list`...

```
$list = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', ...];
```

...that generates an array `$types`...

```
$types = ["Foo" => array(), "Bar" => array(),"Baz" => array(), ...]
```

Is it possible? I have tried doing `array_push($types, $list)` but that just copies the the string array into the last position of `$types`

Comment: there is probably a funkey way, but a simple foreach loop would work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use  [array_fill_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) function

```
$types = array_fill_keys($list, []);
```

Comment: Doesnt this fill them ALL with the exact same? (granted the ! examples are all the same) ... but maybe the Q may want some types to be different? Like a few be arrays, a couple be booleans, strings, etc. But, I'm just guessing.

Comment: Maybe, but it  does not follow from the qestion

Comment: Yup. Answer works exactly as question is. I'm just one of those annoying 'what if' thinkers :p

Comment: If OP will change the question, he will get another answer :) for example, array_combine($list, $anotherArray) :)

Comment: Worked well, thank you! array_combine() was also useful, so thank you twice :)